# My login form doesn't work with Chrome

Tags: php, html, forms, google-chrome

I've tested it with both IE and Firefox, but on Chrome my login form just wont respond. No error messages, no nothing it just doesnt do anything.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" value="<? echo $form->value("user"); ?>"></td><td><? echo $form->error("user"); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30" value="<? echo $form->value("pass"); ?>"></td><td><? echo $form->error("pass"); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" <? if($form->value("remember") != ""){ echo "checked"; } ?>>
<font size="2">Remember me next time &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="sublogin" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

process.php:

```
   function procLogin(){
      global $session, $form;
      /* Login attempt */
      $retval = $session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));

      /* Login successful */
      if($retval){
         header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
      }
      /* Login failed */
      else{
         $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
         $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
         header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
      }
   }
```

session.php:

```
function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember){
      global $database, $form;  //The database and form object

      /* Username error checking */
      $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
      if(!$subuser || strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
      }
      else{
         /* Check if username is not alphanumeric */
         if(!eregi("^([0-9a-z])*$", $subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
         }
      }

      /* Password error checking */
      $field = "pass";  //Use field name for password
      if(!$subpass){
         $form->setError($field, "* Password not entered");
      }

      /* Return if form errors exist */
      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;
      }

      /* Checks that username is in database and password is correct */
      $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
      $result = $database->confirmUserPass($subuser, md5($subpass));

      /* Check error codes */
      if($result == 1){
         $field = "user";
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not found");
      }
      else if($result == 2){
         $field = "pass";
         $form->setError($field, "* Invalid password");
      }

      /* Return if form errors exist */
      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;
      }

      /* Username and password correct, register session variables */
      $this->userinfo  = $database->getUserInfo($subuser);
      $this->username  = $_SESSION['username'] = $this->userinfo['username'];
      $this->userid    = $_SESSION['userid']   = $this->generateRandID();
      $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];

      /* Insert userid into database and update active users table */
      $database->updateUserField($this->username, "userid", $this->userid);
      $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
      $database->removeActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

      if($subremember){
         setcookie("cookname", $this->username, time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
         setcookie("cookid",   $this->userid,   time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
      }

      /* Login completed successfully */
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: If you call var_dump("Hello"); exit(); at the top of your code, do you at least see that?

Comment: It's not gonna be the PHP code. That runs on your server, not Chrome, the client. What's the generated code look like when you `view-source:` (Ctrl + U) in Chrome?

Comment: Hmm what exactly is going there... Is your form getting posted and then noting happens or it just don't get posted at all ??

Comment: Ok errhmm you lot are confusing me.

Comment: I click "Submit" but nothing happens

Comment: Try setting a "name" to the submit button

Comment: Can you copy the HTML source from the form page in your browser, and add it to your question? Need to see what output PHP is putting in the form.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure about it, but try closing your input tags. i mean add "/>" at last.

Comment: @SimplePimple: Push Ctrl + U on the page that doesn't work. Add the code you get to your question.

Comment: That depends, Eric.  Yes, it would be the browsers fault.  However, for instance, if you have a submit button that's an image button named "Submit", on Internet Explorer instead of getting `$_POST['Submit']` you get `$_POST['Submit_x']` and `$_POST['Submit_y']`.  On Firefox, you'd get all 3.  So, it's possible that looking at the HTML source might not help at all.  The problem could be in the PHP code that checks if the form has been properly submitted or not before it actually tries to log the user in.

Comment: This has left out so much of the other code you can't see where you're starting from

Comment: *sigh* people still use tables for forms..

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem when using jpWare, which is what your code is based on.

The problem occurs when you use the "remember me" function on one browser, then log in on a different browser. This is caused by the php trying to use the data stored in the outdated cookies to validate your sessionId.

To solve the problem have the PHP delete those cookies during log in. As follows:

```
  /* Insert userid into database and update active users table */
  $database->updateUserField($this->username, "userid", $this->userid);
  $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
  $database->removeActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if($subremember){
        setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, $this->customer_id, time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
        setcookie(COOKIE_ID,   $this->session_id,   time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
    } else {
    /* Delete cookies - This fixes a bug that wouldn't let you log in if your
     * session_id got changed (by another browser for example) but your cookies
     * still referenced the old one.
     */
    setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, $this->customer_id, time(), COOKIE_PATH);
    setcookie(COOKIE_ID,   $this->session_id,   time(), COOKIE_PATH);}
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to assign a "name" to your button, then in your process.php, make a check if this button is pressed, and then to everything else...Checking should be something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_name'])){
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must have the same number of td:s on each row in a table.
As the first 2 rows has 3 cells, so must also the last row with the colspan have 3.